# Unable to click on the next page button containing ">" sign

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in Python in combination with Selenium to grab some phone numbers from a website. To find the content of any state it is necessary to enter city names in the appropriate search box and press the search button. I did it the right way with "Orlando" as the city name. However, upon pressing the search button a list of documents come up which are traversing different pages through pagination. My script can do all this except for clicking the next button. How can I mend my script to click on the next page button until no more next page button is left? Thanks in advance.

The link I'm working with: [the link](http://www.facdl.org/page/find-a-lawyer).

Script I'm trying with:

```
from selenium import webdriver;import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("above link")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='city']"))).send_keys("Orlando")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn-primary"))).click()
time.sleep(5)

while True:

    try:

        link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pagination a")))

        if link.text == ">":

            print(link.text)
            link.click()
            time.sleep(5)

    except:

        break

driver.quit()
```

Next page elements are within:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="(function(tgt){var rt={};rt=$.parseJSON(unescape('%7B%22fname%22%3A%22%22%2C%22lname%22%3A%22%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Naples%22%2C%22tcustom11%22%3A%22%22%2C%22icustom12%22%3A%22%22%2C%22uat_1%22%3A%22%22%2C%22icustom43%22%3A%220%22%2C%22near%22%3A%22%22%2C%22dist%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2258%22%2C%22lat%22%3A%22%22%2C%22lon%22%3A%22%22%2C%22co%22%3A%22%22%7D'));rt.p=2;soc.ajax('cp','ld','ajax',rt);})(this);return false;">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="(function(tgt){var rt={};rt=$.parseJSON(unescape('%7B%22fname%22%3A%22%22%2C%22lname%22%3A%22%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Naples%22%2C%22tcustom11%22%3A%22%22%2C%22icustom12%22%3A%22%22%2C%22uat_1%22%3A%22%22%2C%22icustom43%22%3A%220%22%2C%22near%22%3A%22%22%2C%22dist%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2258%22%2C%22lat%22%3A%22%22%2C%22lon%22%3A%22%22%2C%22co%22%3A%22%22%7D'));rt.p=2;soc.ajax('cp','ld','ajax',rt);})(this);return false;">&gt;</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="(function(tgt){var rt={};rt=$.parseJSON(unescape('%7B%22fname%22%3A%22%22%2C%22lname%22%3A%22%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Naples%22%2C%22tcustom11%22%3A%22%22%2C%22icustom12%22%3A%22%22%2C%22uat_1%22%3A%22%22%2C%22icustom43%22%3A%220%22%2C%22near%22%3A%22%22%2C%22dist%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2258%22%2C%22lat%22%3A%22%22%2C%22lon%22%3A%22%22%2C%22co%22%3A%22%22%7D'));rt.p=2;soc.ajax('cp','ld','ajax',rt);})(this);return false;">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

Next page button looks like:

```
">"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://www.facdl.org/page/find-a-lawyer")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='city']"))).send_keys("Orlando")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn-primary"))).click()
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    try:
        link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, ">")))
        link.click()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(link))
    except:
        break
```

I've added `time.sleep(2)` to wait until page is scrolled and became static. Also `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(link))` to wait for new button instance creation

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your solution. Forgot about `link text` so kept trying on and on with css selectors. This staleness usage is something new.

Answer (score 1):

You could do in this way:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='city']"))).send_keys("Orlando")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn-primary"))).click()

while True:
    try:
        link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='text-center']/ul[@class='pagination']/li/a[contains(text(), '>')]")))
        link.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        print("finish!")
        break

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, please:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("http://www.facdl.org/page/find-a-lawyer")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "city"))).send_keys("Orlando")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-primary"))).click()

while True:

    try:

        link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, ">")))
        link.click()
        time.sleep(2)

    except:

        break
```