# Can't make a loop run in my script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is the follow up question of [The Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120755/unable-to-click-on-the-next-page-button-containing-sign) this thread. I expected my script to parse the name and phone from the first page and then click on the next page button and do the same until all the next page links are exhausted. However, when i execute my below script (the portion within the while loop) individually, it works but when the both get wrapped within the while loop then the latter part , i meant the pagination portion fails to execute. I tried several times but the consequence is always the same. How can i fix it so that it will parse documents from the first page and click on the next page links to do the rest?

The script:

```
while True:
    for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ajaxBtn"))):
        item.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        root = fromstring(driver.page_source)
        try:
            name = root.cssselect("#popclick .modal-header .h4")[0].text.strip()
            phone = root.cssselect("td:contains('Phone:')+td")[0].text.strip()
        except:
            pass
        print(name,phone)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#popclick .modal-header button"))).click()
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {})".format(item.location['y']))

    try:
        link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, ">")))
        link.click()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(link))
    except:
        break
```

Comment: How about insert `time.sleep(3)` everywhere. The difference between manual and `while-loop` is just time I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just iterate through all the pages you click ">" button on the top pagination (visible one), but when you do the same along with scraping you scroll page down to bottom pagination. In this case top pagination is no more visible, so your loop brakes on

```
try:
    link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, ">")))
    link.click()
```

as you cannot click ">" on the top.

You need to handle bottom pagination. Just replace

```
link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, ">")))
```

with

```
link = driver.find_elements_by_link_text(">")[1]
```

Comment: You are invincible sir Andersson. Just perfect. I could understand the concept but curious to know why the index become `[1]` instead of just `[0]`. Although you made it clear, it would be easier for me if you make a oneliner comment on it. Thanks again sir.

Comment: Index `[0]` is for ">" on top pagination, `[1]` is for the same on bottom pagination

Comment: Thanks sir for everything.